Movie/TV show where divorce lawyer takes a fish out of water
My wife and I are trying to remember a movie or TV show scene we saw, but can't think of the title for the life of us.  As I recall, someone is talking with a divorce lawyer of some sort, and the lawyer in the room (female) takes a fish out of her aquarium and leaves it on the table sputtering and gasping for breath, drawing an analogy to what they're going to do to the husband.  She eventually puts it back into the water, implying they'll let the husband be once he plays game with them.  I've spent hours on Google trying to find a reference to the scene and have come up with nothing.
Movie was in english, real life, US production, and in color.

Welcome to Movies.SE! We have a minimum requirement for ID questions on this site. Do you remember when/where/how you watched this movie? What language was it in? Was it an American production, or from a different country? Was it real life or animated? Was it in color? We'll need answers to these questions to help us track down an answer to this question.  If you have this information, please edit it into your question.

I believe this is from an episode of Weeds (Showtime and then on Netflix) when Celia Hodes wants to divorce her husband Dean. Sounds like season 2 poss. She is using this fish gasping as description of how they will stick it too him and as he's about to suffocate they'll throw him back in the water to be happy to be alive. 

Thats what I thought!  I googled "weeds fish on table" and "celia hodes fish out of water" and couldn't find anything.  Thank you so much.

My Pleasure, glad I could help!

To add to it, its season 3 episode 3 "The Brick Dance" opening scene of the episode. Carrie Fisher is the divorce attorney too!
